# Design Patterns for a Visual Editor

Tags: c++, qt, box2d

I'm creating an visual editor for Box2D ( an 2d physics engine for games).

Like the most tools out there, my program has editor tools, that currently support two kind: polygon and circle tools

Here it is ( I'm using Qt to design the application)
[image]

As you can see, the two selectable tools are in the left.

The question is : Qt sends signals to QGraphicItem ( something that has already been drawn to the screen) when the item is clicked. However the behaviour of the program depends on which tool is selected. Which is the best way to solve this problem? Each drawing has to know which tool is selected? This doesn't sound good for me...

Exemplifying:
If I selected Polygon and I click into somewhere , it should start to draw a polygon. If I click into a Polygon vertex, it should edit it. If I selected circle tool and I click in a polygon vertex, it should start drawing a circle instead of editing the polygon.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?  You can query which tool is selected from your slot.

Comment: Although this is based on opinion, if you have the polygon tool selected and you click on a polygon then it should not begin to edit the polygon; it should create a new polygon.  You should have a third *select* tool, that allows you to select and edit existing items.  Otherwise how would you create a polygon within another polygon.

Comment: @dunc123
The problem is that solution would require that every kind of item have to know the behaviour of every tool. It would be somehow redundant
About the editing information... I guess I agree with you

Comment: If you follow the editing behaviour then the problem mostly goes away.  Your drawing tools only act on the canvas, not the items themselves.  The editing tools act on the items and would most likely require different code depending on the item being selected.